# CaseIterableはSwift4.2から使えるとネットにあるが、Swift4で動いているように感じる

Tags: swift, swift4

画像のようにSwift4を設定しています。
ネットにはSwift4.2から使えると書いています。

しかし`CaseIterable`を書いてみるとコンパイルが通り正常に動きました。
なぜでしょうか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

参考：
- https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/77/whats-new-in-swift-4-2
- https://dev.classmethod.jp/smartphone/iphone/wwdc18-swift-4-2-case-iterable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift 4どころか、Swift 3を指定しても、`CaseIterable`が使えませんか?

Xcode 10.xに付属するSwiftコンパイラは、Swift 4.2.xであり、リンクされるSwift標準ライブラリもSwift 4.2用のものです。

Build Settingsにある、Swift Language Versionは、あくまでもSwift 4.2コンパイラをどのモードで走らせるかという指定であり、動作がSwift 3コンパイラやSwift 4コンパイラと全く同じになるわけではありません。Swift 4.2で導入された機能のうち、Swift 3モードやSwift 4モードの動作と矛盾しないものは、それらのモードを指定しても使えたりします。

また構文は全く変わらないままSwift標準ライブラリの挙動が変更になっている場合などは、Swift 3/4を指定していても、Swift 4.2標準ライブラリの挙動となります。

`CaseIterable`の他にもSwift 4.2で導入された機能(下の例は`offset(of:)`)がSwift 3/4モードで動くかと思います。試してみてください。

```
struct MyStruct {
    var i32: Int32
    var i16: Int16
}
if let offs = MemoryLayout.offset(of: \MyStruct.i16) {
    print(offs) //-> 4
}
```

Comment: 質問文には書きませんでしたが、仰る通り他にも○○はSwiftの○○のバージョンから使えると書かれているのに、動いてしまう例を何回か経験しました。

Comment: モードと言語バージョンとはどのように違うのでしょうか？。別質問にしたほうが良さそうなら別の質問を作ります。

Comment: Swiftの場合、言語バージョンというより「コンパイラ&標準ライブラリのバージョン」ですが、きちんとしたドキュメントがないので、別質問にしてもらっても完全な答えを持っている人がいるかどうかは難しいでしょうね。モードを変えると「Swift 3→Swift 4→Swift 4.2で構文そのものが変わっている(単にメソッド名が変わっているものも含めて)場合、モードの指定で古い構文が使える」、「`@objc`が要るか要らないか、のように(Swift言語開発者がはっきり意識している)大きな挙動の変化がある場合、指定したバージョンの挙動でコンパイルしてくれる」と言ったところでしょうか。例えばiOSアプリではほぼ必ず実装される`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)`なんてメソッドは引数のデータ型がSwift 3...Swift 4.2で変化しているんですが、Swift 3モードを指定しておくと、古い書き方でもコンパイルしてくれます。

Comment: なるほどお。ドキュメントがそろっていないのは難しいですねぇ。